# issue using $_POST in html and php

Tags: php, html, get

I am having serious issue with $_POST and $_GET. I am new to php. Just started it a week ago.

I have  a html form which calls php for the action.

```
<html><body>
<form action="ls_sample1.php" method="post">Submission ID: <input type="text" name="sub_id" />
<input type="submit"/></form>
</body></html>
```

I have a php which takes the sub_id and exectute the system command

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>

<?php
$input = $_POST['sub_id'];
echo "Entered submission id is $input";
system('/auto/ash/g2k/bin/gt -F stat -s $input',$ret);
if($ret) {
 echo "its invalid input because return value is $ret";
}
?>
```

ignore the command that is in the above code. It is just like any other unix command. When I execute in the shell, everything works fine and return value will be 0. When I execute it in the browser the  return value is 1 and nothing executes. However the submission id is getting passed to the php.

Browser output:
Entered submission id is 0000268801 its invalid input because return value is 1

Am I missing anything here?? Please help.

Comment: When shelling out, I believe the command gets executed as a different user: www-data usually. Does that user have permissions to execute the command?

Comment: Are you expecting `$input` to be expanded in a single quote string?

Comment: single quotes mean $input wont be 'expanded' to the variable content, use doubles

Comment: Thanks a lot Dagon. Ya the double quote was the issue.

Answer (score 4):

So... no. Don't do this.

If someone submits the form such that the input field contains this:

```
 ; rm -rf ~/ #
```

Then you've got trouble. And they can be much more malicious than just deleting all your files.

Have a look at [escapeshellarg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php).

**WRT your error:**

Return code 1 typically signifies a general (unspecified) error. Occasionally PHP will dump something into your error logs that might be helpful. You could check to make sure that your apache user actually has permission to run this program, and that nothing in your php.ini file is interfering.

Failing at all of the simple solutions, what I would do is `strace` the Apache instance and see what happens. This is a bit more advanced, but if you know how to use the tool then it's pretty indispensable. I'd temporarily change the apache config down such that there's only one apache worker process, attach to it with strace and dump the output to a file. Then search the file for the name of your executable and follow the execution chain from there. Eventually you'll hit the error and see what it is. You might also pay attention to the `-s` option to strace (which controls where it truncates strings), `-w` which sets the output file, and `-t` or `-tt` which adds timestamps.

Please don't ask me to explain how to do all that stuff; it would take pages.

Comment: if you have the web server's user permission set to that would work, that would be the first thing to fix

Comment: @Dagon don't rely on permissions to save you. `rm -rf` is just an example to show that it's dangerous. What's more *likely* is downloading and executing a back door program. And your permissions won't save you there.

Comment: should still be the first port of call, low to high security.

Comment: what's in your web-server users home dir? mine is empty

Comment: Ya this not my final form. I was trying to test my sample script. Thanks for your inputs. Definitely will take that into consideration.